# Create custom hook without passing props in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to learning React with Typescript and so far, I have read a lot about typing props and I just don't understand how to create a custom hook **without** having to pass props, here's an example:

```
import { useState, useEffect, FunctionComponent, ReactElement } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface PostData {
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}


const usePosts = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<PostData[]>([]);

  const getPosts = () => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      
    })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return {
    posts,
  };
};

export default usePosts;
```

In this case, ESlint is saying that **const usePosts = () => ...** is Missing return type on function.

Comment: When I run this in `Typescript Playground` I do not get the same warning as you do. I think you have `explicit-function-return-type` enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this (I cut your exemple in multiple file for more clarity): 
your hooks just add the return type  like this: 
**usePost.hook.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface PostData {
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}


const usePosts = ():PostData[] => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<PostData[]>([]);

  const getPosts = () => {
    axios.get<PostData[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
     setPosts(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      
    })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return posts;
};

export default usePosts;
```

you can see an exemple of your code in this [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sv651?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Oh I see, so here we are passing the type (or multiple types) that we are going to use in our function, right?